# Instagram API Business Information

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Does anyone know if there is an endpoint for business information in the Instagram API. Their docs do not display this but it's a relatively new feature and we all know how documentation gets left behind sometimes.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing. Does anyone have any news regarding this?

Comment: What are the business information you need to retrieve from? If you just need to know if the instagram account is set as business, the user endpoint from Instagram API has already been updated to return this information.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram just released a new [api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.10) that utilizes the old Facebook Graph API. It allows you to read insights and receive more business stats. The only downside is that the api is in beta and only available to 'select partners'.